# My users are automatically logged out after 15-20 minutes, and I don't want that

Tags: php, session, cookies

There is a problem on my site. The users on my site are logged out in case of inactivity. I want users to log out when they want. I didn't set any cookies and session variables for logged. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: How is the login etc managed, without cookies?

Comment: I think he put their names in the url..my best bet.. .. so the url change could be your culprit

Comment: `I did'nt set any cookies and session varibale for logged` How do you know somebody is logged in then? This smells funny! Probably you're doing it wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has a default session timeout; just because you didn't specify it doesn't mean it doesn't exist.

[Google is your friend.](https://www.google.com/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=cross%20domain%20man%20in%20the%20middle&safe=active#pq=cross%20domain%20man%20in%20the%20middle&hl=en&cp=19&gs_id=21&xhr=t&q=php%20default%20session%20timeout&tok=SHydUFUOKHQqT1GxqkLWpA&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&safe=active&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=php%20default%20session&aq=0&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=a1bc1589ec616832&biw=1278&bih=939)